# How to combine stream name in AWS cloudfront?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cloudfront

Amazon Cloudfront SDK and example code - how do I combine the stream name? All the other functions are spelled out, but I can't see any definition or example for create_stream_name().

Below is the complete code from the example as described in the documentation here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html

As you can see, the function create_stream_name() does not appear anywhere but is called in line 12, which will result in a "call to undefined function" error. How should I define create_stream_name()?

```
function get_canned_policy_stream_name($video_path, $private_key_filename, $key_pair_id, $expires) {
        // this policy is well known by CloudFront, but you still need to sign it, 
        // since it contains your parameters
        $canned_policy = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"' . $video_path . '","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":'. $expires . '}}}]}';

        // sign the canned policy
        $signature = $this->rsa_sha1_sign($canned_policy, $private_key_filename);
        // make the signature safe to be included in a url
        $encoded_signature = $this->url_safe_base64_encode($signature);

        // combine the above into a stream name
        $stream_name = create_stream_name($video_path, null, $encoded_signature, $key_pair_id, $expires);
        // url-encode the query string characters to work around a flash player bug
    return encode_query_params($stream_name);
}



function rsa_sha1_sign($policy, $private_key_filename) {
    $signature = "";

    // load the private key
    $fp = fopen($private_key_filename, "r");
    $priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
    fclose($fp);
    $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);

    // compute signature
    openssl_sign($policy, $signature, $pkeyid);

    // free the key from memory
    openssl_free_key($pkeyid);

    return $signature;
}

function url_safe_base64_encode($value) {
    $encoded = base64_encode($value);
    // replace unsafe characters +, = and / with 
    // the safe characters -, _ and ~
    return str_replace(
        array('+', '=', '/'),
        array('-', '_', '~'),
        $encoded);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `create_stream_name()` is defined in the full example (demo.php) which you can download at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/samples/demo-php.zip. The full example is linked to at the top of the documentation page, though it's somewhat obscured behind the text "Signature Code for Video Streaming in PHP." [**Update:** It's no longer obscured, see below.]

Full disclosure: I'm the person responsible for that documentation page, so I'll do a couple of things to make it better:

- Make the link to the full sample more discoverable. [**Update:** The download URL for the full example is now more prominent at the top of [the documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html).]
- Add the full example to the page, so you can see and copy it right off the page, rather than having to download a zip file. [**Update:** The full example is now [published at the bottom of the documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html#full-example).]